# PHP Script dies due to expired time while getting from memcached

Tags: php, memcached

I have a situation where I need rapid and very frequent updates from a website's API. (I've asked them about how fast I can hammer them and they've said as fast as you like.)

So my design architecture is to create several small fast running PHP scripts that do a very specific action, save the result to memcache, and repeat. So the first script grabs a single piece of data via their API and stores it in memcache and then asks again. A second script processes the data the first script stored in memcache and requests another piece of data from the API based on the results of that processing. The third uses the result from the second, does something with that data, asks for more data via the API, on up the chain until a decision is made to execute via their API.

I am running these scripts in parallel on a machine with 24 GB RAM and 8 cores. I am also using supervisor in order to manage them.

When I run every PHP script manually via CLI or browser they work fine. They don't die except where I've told them to for the browser so I can get some feedback. The logic is fine, the scripts runs fine, etc, etc.

However, when I leave them running infinitely vai supervisor the logs fill up with Maximum execution time reached errors and the line it points to is line in one of my classes that gets the data from memcache. Sometimes it bombs on a check to see if the data is JSON (which it should always be), sometimes it bombs elsewhere in the same function/method. The timeout is set for the supervisor managed script is 5 sec because the data is stale by then.

I have considered upping the execution time but

- the data will be stale by then,
- memcache typically returns in less than 1 msec so 5 sec is an eternity,
- none of the scripts have ever failed due to timeout when manually (CLI or browser) run

Environment:
Ubuntu 12.04 Server
PHP 5.3.10-1unbuntu3.9 with Suhosin-Patch
Memcached 1.4.13
Supervisor ??

Memcache Stats (from phpMemcachdAdmin):

```
Size: 1 GB
Uptime: 17 hrs, 38 min
Hit Rate: 76.5%
Used: 18.9 MB
Wasted: 18.9 MB
Bytes Written: 307.8 GB
Bytes Read: 7.2 GB
```

Here's a screenshot:
[image: phpMemcachedAdmin Screen Capture]

--------------- Additional Thoughts/Questions ----------------

I don't think it was clear in my original post that in order to get rapid updates I am running multiple copies in parallel of the scripts that grab API data. So if one script is grabbing basic account data looking for a change to trigger another event, then I actually have at least 2 instances running concurrently. This is because my biggest risk factor is stale data causing a delayed decision combined with a 1+ sec response time from the API.

So it occurred to me that the issue may stem from write conflicts where 2 instances of the same script are attempting to write to the same cache key. My initial Googling didn't lead to any good material on possible write conflicts/collisions in memcache. However, a little deeper dive provided a page where a user with 2 bookmarking sites powered by Elgg off of 1 memcache instance ran into what he described as collisions.

My initial assumption when deciding to kick multiple instances off in parallel was that Supervisor would kick them off in a sequential and therefore slightly staggered manner (maybe a bad assumption, I'm new to using Supervisor). Additionally, the API would respond at different rates to each call. Thus with a write time in the sub-millisecond time frame and an update from each once every 1-2 seconds the chances of write conflicts/collisions seemed pretty low.

I'm considering using some form of prefix/postfix with the keys. Each instance already has it's own instance ID created from an md5 hash. So I could prefix or postfix and then have each instance write to it's own key. But then I need another key that holds all of those prefixed/postfixed keys. So now I'm doing multiple cache fetches, a loop through all the stored data, and a discard of all but one of those results. I bet there's a better/faster architecture out there...

I am adding the code to do the timing Aziz asked for now. It will take some time to add the code and gather the data.

Recommendations welcome

Comment: +1 Seems like an interesting problem. Have you tried running the cronjobs as the same user supervisor is running on, could be a permission thing (not sure why it would be since all you do is data manipulation).

Comment: @AzizSaleh The supervisor conf files have the scripts all running as me via a CLI command. I've checked and they are running via my user. I can run the scripts manually without issue and memcache doesn't ask for any credentials.

Comment: Can you try adding time logging to see where the bottleneck is? What slows this down when its run via sv, is it the retrieval of data via the API or the Memcached read/writes.

Comment: @AzizSaleh The script I was looking at before writing the question is the 2nd to last step in the chain. It is processing already grabbed API data but makes no API calls itself. Additionally, the script is a loop with set_time_limit(5) at the beginning of the loop. It reads a bunch from Memcache, does some math, outputs the result to Memcache. The write is at the very end of the loop and the timeout error always traces back to one of the reads.